# How can I get all the records that are in a intermediate table only once?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This maybe is a complex question, but I'll try to explain at best.

I have the following models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Order(models.Model):
    requester = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    taker = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models. EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class Picture(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    show_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture)
    amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

I need to get all the Orders that belong to an Event, but only once. This can be achieved by the Pictures. If a Picture is in an Order, I need the Event.

Example:

```
Event 1:
Pic 1, Pic 2

Event 2:
Pic 3, Pic 4

Order 1:
Pic 1, Pic 2, Pic 3, Pic 4

Order 2:
Pic 2

Order 3:
Pic 1
```

What I need:

```
Event 1 has 3 Orders (Order 1, Order 2 and Order 3)
Event 2 has 1 Order (Order 1)
```

Even if the Order contains several pictures from the Event, I just need it to count one time.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has no difference than any other queries, just use double underscore to change the relation:

```
event = Event.objects.get(id=1)
orders = Order.objects.filter(orderitem__picture__event=event)
```

**Edit:**

To count the orders you do:

```
order_count = orders.distinct().count()
```

Comment: Yes! I am getting the Orders, but how can I make it to count only once? It returns a list with every Order, but with multiple Orders.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.